# How can I change margin and block size in a class definition based on Memoir?

Tags: memoir, documentclass-writing

Given the following example:

**test.cls**:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{test}
\LoadClass[article,oneside]{memoir}

\setstocksize{3in}{3in}
\settrimmedsize{3in}{3in}
%\setlrmarginsandblock{5pt}{5pt}{*}
%\setulmarginsandblock{5pt}{*}{1}
\checkandfixthelayout
```

**test.tex**:

```
\documentclass[foo]{test}
\begin{document}
foo bar buzz
\end{document}
```

I get something that looks like:

[image]

But if I remove the commented lines in test.cls I get:

```
! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...

l.7     \setlrmarginsandblock{5
                               pt}{5pt}{*}
?
```

Why is this? Why are those commands different from the trimmedsize and stocksize and how can I fix the margins and block?

Comment: Please read the manual: `\settrimmedsize` takes 3 arguments not 2. And then you'll have to adjust headheight accordingly

Comment: Ooppss, @daleif sorry for bothering you with my sloppiness :(

Comment: No worries, we've all been there

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it asks a simple question that should be looked up in the manual in a complicated way that makes it hard to stumble upon while googling